# Change MUI MobileDatePicker style using DatePicker component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have component

```
<DatePicker
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    renderInput={params =>
        <TextField
            margin="dense"
            variant="outlined"
            {...params}
            inputProps={{
                ...params.inputProps,
                placeholder: t('DD.MM.YYYY')
            }}
        />
    }
/>
```

I want to change height of only mobile version modal to make ok button visible

[image: mobile version of mui datepicker]